# difference between intent and intenfilter in android

Tags: android

Hi friends 
can anybody tell what is the use of intent filter and what is difference between intent and intent  filter

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An Intent is an object passed to **Context.startActivity(),Context.startService()  or Activity.startActivityForResult() etc.** to launch an activity or get an existing activity to do something new.

While an Intent filter describes a capability of the component(like activities, services, and broadcast receivers )

For more details see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 2):

Intent's are used to start new activity from the current activity. With two ways
1) Activity.startActivity(intent);
2) Activity.startActivityForResult(intent,rqwuestCode);
//The above thing's you need to put in .java file

Intent-filter you need to mention on manifeast file.

// Intent filter are used for broadcast receiver.  Whenever the intent filter condition is match the android OS will launch that activity.

Answer (score 0):

An intent is an object that can hold the os or other app activity and its data in uri form.It is started using startActivity(intent-obj)..\n whereas IntentFilter can fetch activity information on os or other app activities.